# Authentication and AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, authentication

I want to add authentication to existing application that uses Ajax and I am thinking of the best way to do it. 
Here is a typical scenario:

1. First request - ask for a login, proceed to the first screen.  This works well.
2. Session expired.

Since I do ajax and send 2 requests per action (one actual request and one that records the action for statistics/audit) it could happen on one of those. When it happens the app shows me the authentication screen and after successful authentication user is forwarded to the previous request.

The problem here is that I don't want a forward, I want my custom Ajax/javascript handling to get the response and handle it. Is it possible to just pop up a window to authenticate, then when I get the response continue like the session never expired?

I have this in the web.xml :

```
   <login-config>
       <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
       <form-login-config>
           <form-login-page>/jsp/login.jsp</form-login-page>
           <form-error-page>/jsp/login_error.jsp</form-error-page>
       </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question seems to be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323038/handling-authentication-through-ajax

Comment: I don't think it is the same, first I don't use PHP, I use Java and JSP, second, the question you are referring to deals with the server side, I already have this handled, I just need to know how to handle the case when the authentication comes back when the session is expired.

Comment: Why don't you just make 1 request and manage the recording for statics/audit directly in your server code?

Comment: @RomanHoyenko Well you should note that you 'use Java and JSP' in your question then. ^_^

Comment: added jsp to the question and put some of the login-config I have in web.xml

Comment: it's a big app, I added stats gathering after the app was written since we only have 2-3 entry points in GUI where we do actions and we have a lot of entry points in the server code. If it is not possible to do one request, I would do it but I want to see if I can do with the system I have in place.